# PIC16F886 and Switch Setup with Diode

Tags: diodes, pic, embedded, input, pins

[image]I would like to make a simple embedded program that will Display what is happening on and LCD screen. When Switch One is pressed, it displays "Switch One". When Switch 2 is pressed it displays Switch 2 so on. For Switches 7 and 8 I would like to have a diode in Circuit as you can see from the Schematic.

As you can see from the schematic I have 2 Diodes on Switch 7 and 2 Diodes on Switch 8. IF I reverse the Diodes the program runs correctly and when Switches 7 and 8 are pressed they are Displayed correctly on the Display. I would like to have the Diodes reversed though. So I somehow need to reverse the way the Pins are reading from Input to Output...or from High to Low or vice versa. My concept of Inputs, Outputs, Highs, and Lows, are not quite up to par yet:):) Any help is greatly appreciated!!:):)

Here is the code in which runs perfectly IF the Diodes are reversed. It may not be able to even be done. I have spent hours trying to get this to work and I am now at a loss as to what I need to do. My brain is fried!!

Thanks again for any help you guys!!

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define _LEGACY_HEADERS
#include <htc.h>
#include "lcd.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////DEFINE STATEMENTS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define SWITCH1     RB0
#define SWITCH2     RB1
#define SWITCH3     RB2
#define SWITCH4     RB3
#define SWITCH5     RB4
#define SWITCH6     RB5



#define DelayS(T)       {unsigned char i; for (i = 0; i < T * 10; i++) __delay_ms(100);}    //Delay Macro
//#define _XTAL_FREQ                4000000                             //Needs to be set for __delay_ms
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////CONFIGURATION FUSES (BITS)
////Master Clear Reset enabled & Internal RC No Clock & Watchdog Timer Disable & Power Up Timer On & Brown Out Reset Disabled &
////Low Voltage Porgramming Disabled & Code Unprotect
__CONFIG (MCLRDIS & INTIO & WDTDIS & PWRTEN & BORDIS & LVPDIS & UNPROTECT);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


main()
{
   PORTA = 0x00;                                        //PORTA is cleared  
   PORTA = 0xE9;                                        //(ob11101001 binary) (0xE9 hex)
                                                    //PORTA7:A0 is set to high,high,high,low,high,low,low,high
                                                    
   PORTB = 0x00;                                        //PORTB is cleared
   PORTB = 0xFF;                                        //(0b11111111 binary) (0xFF hex)  
                                                    //PORTB7:B0 is set to high,high,high,high,high,high,high,high
                                                    
   PORTC = 0x00;                                        //PORTC is cleared
   PORTC = 0xF0;                                        //PORTC is set to high, high, high, high, low, low, low, low


   TRISA = 0xE9;                                        //(0b11101001 binary)   (0xE9 hex)
                                                    //LCD--RA1, RA2, RA4 are Control lines for LCD
                                                    //RA0, RA3, RA5, RA6 are set for switches
                                                    //PORTA7:A0 is set to input,input,input,output,input,output,output,input

   TRISB = 0xFF;                                        //(0b11111111 binary) (0xFF hex) 
                                                    //All of PORTB are set for switches
                                                    //PORTB7:B0 is set to input,input,input,input,input,input,input,input
                                                

   TRISC = 0x00;                                        //(0b00000000 binary) (0x00 hex)
                                                    //All of PORTC is set for LCD
                                                    //PORTC7:C0 is set to output,output,output,output,output,output,output,output
                                                    

   ANSEL = 0;                                           //Initialize A/D Ports off
   ANSELH = 0;                                          //Initialize ........
   ADCON0 = 0;
   ADCON1 = 0;
   CM1CON0 = 0;                                     //Initialize Comparator 1 off
   CM2CON0 = 0;                                     //Initialize Comparator 2 off
                                    

   OPTION = 0b01010101;                             //OPTION REG
                                                    //xbxxxxx101  1:64
                                                    //xbxxxx0xxx  Prescaler set to Timer0
                                                    //xbxxx1xxxx  (T0SE) set to Increment on high-to-low transition on T0CKI pin
                                                    //xbxx0xxxxx  (T0CS) Internal instruction cycle clock
                                                    //xbx1xxxxxx  (INTEDG) Interrupt on rising edge of INT pin
                                                    //xb0xxxxxxx  (RBPU) PORTB pull-ups are enabled by individual PORT latch values
   RBPU = 0;                                            //Don't think I need this, but to be safe...PORTB Weak Internal Pullups enabled
   WPUB0 = 1;                                           //COL_1 Weak pullup is individually ENABLED--INPUT 
   WPUB1 = 1;                                           //COL_2 Weak Pullup is inidivdually ENABLED--INPUT
   WPUB2 = 1;                                           //Not being used...Weak Pullup is individually ENABLED
   WPUB3 = 1;                                           //ROW_1 Weak Pullup is individually ENABLED--INPUT
   WPUB4 = 1;                                           //ROW_2 Weak Pullup is individually ENABLED--INPUT
   WPUB5 = 1;                                           //ROW_3 Weak Pullup is individually ENABLED--INPUT
   WPUB6 = 1;                                           //ROW_4 Weak Pullup is individually ENABLED--INPUT
   WPUB7 = 1;                                           //COL_3 Weak Pullup is individually ENABLED--INPUT


   lcd_init();                                          //LCD Display is Initialized...See LCD.C file and LCD.h
   lcd_clear();

   char a;                                                  //
   char b;                                                  //

//The following Code will Display the name of the tester and the Rev. only once for a total of 
//2 seconds.  This happens right when you turn it on.  I had to keep it out of the while statement
//because it keeps cycling over and over again.  Therefore it had to be before that.  After the
//Name and Rev. is displayed for 2 seconds, we have to clear the LCD of the Name and Rev..  Therefore
//the use of lcd_clear is required to clear the screen.  

   lcd_goto(0);                                         //
   lcd_puts("SWITCH_TESTER");                               //
   lcd_goto(40);                                            //
   lcd_puts("Rev. 0.0");                                        //
   __delay_ms(2000);                                        //Display Name and Rev. for 2000 ms (2 seconds)
   lcd_clear();                                         //The Screen is cleared of Name and Rev.

while (1)

    {
        lcd_goto(0);                                    //Go to Line 1 Position 1
        lcd_puts("SWITCH Tester");                      //Display ""
        lcd_goto(40);                                   //Go to Line 2 Position 1
        lcd_puts("Press SWITCH");                       //Display "Press SWITCH"
        b = 0;
        
        while ((SWITCH1 == 0) && (SWITCH5 == 1))                                //While SW1 is 0(Low)(Pressed)...
            {
                __delay_ms(10);                         //Delay 10 ms (Switch Debounce)
                while ((SWITCH1 == 0) && (SWITCH5 == 1))                        //Check to see if SW1 is low after Debounce
                    {
                        for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //For Statement to cycle lcd_clear only once
                            {
                                lcd_clear();            //lcd_clear should only cycle once because a = (b = 0)
                            }
                
                        lcd_goto(0);                    //On LCD go to Position 1 (Line 1, Position 0)
                        lcd_puts("SWITCH 1");           //Display ""
                        b = 1;                          //Char B is now 1 so For Statement cycles once
                    }
            }
        
        while ((SWITCH2 == 0) && (SWITCH6 == 1))                            //While ROW_2 is 0(Low)(Pressed)...
            {                                           //
                __delay_ms(10);                         //
                while ((SWITCH2 == 0) && (SWITCH6 == 1))                        //
                    {                                   //
                        for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //
                            {                           //
                                lcd_clear();            //...
                            }                           //...       
                        lcd_goto(0);                    //...
                        lcd_puts("SWITCH 2");           //Display ""
                        b = 1;                          //
                    }
                                                        //
            }                                           //
        
        while ((SWITCH5 == 0) && (SWITCH1 == 1))                                //While ROW_1 is 0(Low)(Pressed)...
            {                                           //
                __delay_ms(10);                         //
                while ((SWITCH5 == 0) && (SWITCH1 == 1))                        //
                    {                                   //...
                        for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //
                            {                           //  
                                lcd_clear();            //...
                            }                           //...
                        lcd_goto(0);                    //...
                        lcd_puts("SWITCH 5");           //Display ""
                        b = 1;                          //
                    }                                   //
            }                                           //
        while ((SWITCH6 == 0) && (SWITCH2 == 1))                            //If ROW 4 is LOW
            {                                           //...
                __delay_ms(10);                         //
                while ((SWITCH6 == 0) && (SWITCH2 == 1))                            //
                    {                                   //
                        for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //
                            {                           //
                                lcd_clear();            //...
                            }                           //...
                        lcd_goto(0);                    //...
                        lcd_puts("SWITCH 6");           //Display ""
                        b = 1;                          //
                    }                                   //  
            }                                           //
                
    while (SWITCH3 == 0)                                //and If ROW 1 is LOW...
            {                                           //...
                __delay_ms(10);                         //
                while (SWITCH3 == 0)                            //
                    {                                   //
                        for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //
                            {                           //
                                lcd_clear();            //...
                            }                           //...
                        lcd_goto(0);                    //...
                        lcd_puts("SWITCH 3");               //Display ""
                        b = 1;                          //
                    }                                   //
            }                                           //
        
    while (SWITCH4 == 0)                            //if ROW 2 is LOW...
            {                                           //...
                __delay_ms(10);                         //
                while (SWITCH4 == 0)                        //
                    {                                   //
                        for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //
                            {                           //
                                lcd_clear();            //...
                            }                           //...       
                        lcd_goto(0);                    //...
                        lcd_puts("SWITCH 4");           //Display ""
                        b = 1;                          //
                    }                                   //
            }                                           //
        
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Tried changing PortB to High by using 
//PORTB - 0xFF;  
//Input by using 
//TRISB = 0xFF; 
//
//I am sure code codes goes here for Switchs 7 and 8
//
//
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        while ((SWITCH1 == 0) && (SWITCH5 == 0))                                
            {                                           //...
                __delay_ms(10);                         //
                while ((SWITCH1 == 0) && (SWITCH5 == 0))
                        {                                   //
                            for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //
                                {                           //
                                    lcd_clear();            //...
                                }                           //...
                            lcd_goto(0);                    //...
                            lcd_puts("SWITCH 7");               //Display "SW7"
                            b = 1;                          //
                        }
            }                                   //

                                                        //

        while ((SWITCH2 == 0) && (SWITCH6 == 0))                            //
            {                                           //...
                __delay_ms(10);                         //
                while ((SWITCH2 == 0) && (SWITCH6 == 0))
                        {                                   //
                                for (a = b; a < 1; a++)         //
                            {                           //
                                lcd_clear();            //...
                            }                           //...
                        lcd_goto(0);                    //...
                        lcd_puts("SWITCH 8");       //Display ""
                        b = 1;                          //
                        }
            }

}
}
```

Comment: `I would like to have a diode in Circuit` ... why?

Comment: Here's your options: (1) 4 diodes reversed....done (2) change all switches from a common GND to a common +5V, add 8 pull-down resistors to each switch, rewrite code to invert PORTB's input logic...a lot of work.

Comment: you could arrange the switches in a matrix ... either a 2x4 or a 3x3

Comment: The only way it makes sense for diodes to be there is if you are designing a keyboard matrix. If that's not what you are attempting, then I don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no amount of code that can make that schematic work if the diodes are like drawn.

There is no way to read switches 7 and 8, unless you for example reverse the diodes.

Comment: Thanks you guys for the nice responses!!  I appreciate it very much:):).  Would this schematic work if I would tie Switches 7 and 8 to Pins RB6 and RB7.  But still use the diodes like they are in the schematic?

Comment: Yes, you can read the two buttons alright, but pushing any other of the four buttons with diodes would also pull the RB6 or RB7 pin down via diode.